# Ajax post returning error "Not Found"

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, rest

Im having the following ajax cal in my JS file in Durundal ,

```
var dataJSON ={ID : "jo"};
self.js = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: text,
    url: "http://localhost:53081/api/File",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),

    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function (json) {
        alert("Data Returned: " + JSON.stringify(json));
    }
});
```

and my REST api is

```
[HttpPost]
public string upload(string ID)
{



    string givenId = ID;
    return givenId;

}
```

but when i call thsi methos im simply getting error alert . what went wrong

**update**

i have updated my code but now im getting Not found error

Comment: replace  `dataType: String` with  `dataType: "text"` and add `contentType:'application/json'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change string to Text:

```
self.js = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: **Text**,
    url: "url",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),

    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
    },
    success: function (json) {
        alert("Data Returned: " + JSON.stringify(json));
    }
});
```

click [here](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/11/03/ajax-datatypes-in-jquery-format-and-access/) for list of datatype and there representation.

Comment: add 
content type contentType: "application/text"

Comment: if this does not works change datatype to json and contentType to  "application/json"

Comment: If i give  var url= http://localhost:49589/api/files/" +gg;  like this it is working but if i give url:"http://localhost:49589/api/files/" and data:JSON.stringfy(gg) it shows not found error

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the name of the method to be `PostFile`.  I had issues getting this to work without having the proper naming convention, even though I had the `[HttpPost]` attribute at the beginning of the method.

Also: try changing your dataType to "json" and adding the content type:

```
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
```